# Can't mapping resources into jsp - Web spring MVC

Tags: java, css, spring-mvc

I try mapping resource into spring-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="Controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

And include jsp page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/common/common.css"/> ">
```

Css seem not active! 
My struct project:
[Myproject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu6Lh.png)

Comment: how about the ``web.xml``???

Comment: <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: @NguyễnVănTâm remove / before resources in your URL. I have added in my answer. Your project setup looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to resources as follows,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="resources/css/common/common.css"/> ">
```

Also check if you have properly configured your resource directories.